# How can I refine this JS array search function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have the following function:

```
export const functionName = (key) => {
  const data = [
    {
      displayOrder: 0,
      key: 'key-name-1',
    },
    {
      displayOrder: 2,
      key: 'key-name-2',
    },
  ];

  for (let index in data) {
    return data[index].displayOrder === 0
      ? data[index].key
      : data[0].key;
  }
};
```

The purpose of the function is to return the `key` with the lowest displayOrder. This works, but is there a better more slick method to achieve this?

Secondly, how best could I create a similar version to re-order the entire array based on `displayOrder`?

Comment: That doesn't look right. Does it work if there are more items in the array and the array isn't already sorted?

Comment: You hardcoded `0` as the lowest `displayOrder` Is this always the case? or It might be 1 (or any number) is the lowest?

Comment: `data.sort((a, b) => a.displayOrder - b.displayOrder)[0]` would be correct…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper method to use when you want to extract a single thing from an array (and you can't identify the element by itself with `.find`) is to use `.reduce`:

```js
const functionName = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      displayOrder: 0,
      key: 'key-name-1',
    },
    {
      displayOrder: 2,
      key: 'key-name-2',
    },
  ];
  const lowestDisplayObj = data.reduce((lowestObjSoFar, currentObj) => {
    if (currentObj.displayOrder < lowestObjSoFar.displayOrder) return currentObj;
    return lowestObjSoFar;
  }, { displayOrder: Infinity, key: null });
  return lowestDisplayObj.key;
};
console.log(functionName());
```

Note that your current argument to `functionName`, `key`, was unused in your snippet, I'm not sure what it's for.

You could also use .sort() and select the first element in the array, but that's more computationally expensive than it needs to be.

Comment: This works! I stripped some of the logic out and forgot to remove the key.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of array reduce and do something like below.

```js
const data = [{
    displayOrder: 10,
    key: 'key-name-10',
  },
  {
    displayOrder: 2,
    key: 'key-name-2',
  },
  {
    displayOrder: 1,
    key: 'key-name-1 Lowest',
  }
];


let a = data.reduce((prev, item) => {
  if (!prev) {
    return item;
  }
  return (item.displayOrder < prev.displayOrder) ? item : prev;
});
console.log(a.key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
    {
      displayOrder: 0,
      key: 'key-name-1',
    },
    {
      displayOrder: 2,
      key: 'key-name-2',
    },
];

const min = Math.min.apply(null, data.map(({displayOrder}) => +displayOrder));

const obj = data.find((obj) => obj.displayOrder == min);

console.log(obj.key);
```